# SP2010 User Profiles: Setting values to a multivalued property via managed code

Tags: 2010, user-profile-service

Any having experience with SharePoint 2010 and updating the user profiles properties (via managed code/PowerShell)?
We have some problems setting values to a multivalued property. We have tried managed code as well as PowerShell  but can’t set the multivalued properties. See below links:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms546301(v=office.14).aspx

http://get-spscripts.com/2010/07/modify-multi-value-user-profile.html

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

This is a really good question, which I find not to be covered that often.

The whole theory of how to get around it is:

```
$foo = Get-Record
$bar = "value and type of the target field collection"
$foo.SomeField += $bar
$foo | Set-Record
```

This is a general PowerShell example and would work with any multivalue field inside or outside of SharePoint.

I found a good example for SharePoint on msdn via google:

```
foreach($p2 in $_.Item($p).GetTaxonomyTerms())
{
    #valueType: $_.Item($p).Value.GetType() reports as a Taxonomy.Term
    $arProfileProps2 += $p2.Name.ToString();
}
```

[Source here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointadminprevious/thread/0afc1906-598a-407d-95ee-55743793c512)